# Multilanguage website optimized for SEO

Tags: multilingual

I've seen that a good choice of multilanguage while keeping a high performance for SEO, would be a duplicated content in a subfolder for each language, but this way every change must be done once for language, which looks a bit weird, at least to me.

Isn't it a string table like to just modify it with new changes, and keep only one version of the website to prevent errors?

By the way, is that the best approach, or there's something better?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this can be achieved with PHP conditional includes as it preprocess the site before sending to client, and it gets an apparently clear copy of the site in each language, so that SEs would index the site in each language.

Answer (score 0):

Multilanguage websites usually use different contents. For instance, a news agency reports local news (at least focused) for each language. In any case, there is no need (in general) to deliver exact translation, as the audience are quite different. The kind of websites, that you are referring too, usually use automatic translation.

Comment: I need to provide same content, as the audience is at the same location, and can't get an automatic translation.